# ionic3: How to get the dropdow's selected value (in a list) while clicking an another button in same row

Tags: angular, ionic3

I'm creating a shopping cart list using ionic3 (for web). The design is as follows:

[Please find the Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9WLf.png)

And what I've achieved is as follows (code):

```
<ion-row *ngFor="let course_schedules of courseDetails.course_schedules;let i= index" > 

 <ion-col col-2 class="tables">{{course_schedules.schedule_course}}</ion-col>
 // Dropdown
 <ion-col *ngIf="course_schedules.schedule_islesson;" col-3 class="tables">
   <select>
     <option *ngFor="let schedule_lessons of course_schedules.schedule_lessons;let j= index" value="{{schedule_lessons.lessons}}-{{schedule_lessons.price}}">{{schedule_lessons.lessons}} Lessons (€ {{schedule_lessons.price}}/Lesson)</option>
   </select>
 </ion-col>

 <ion-col col-2 class="tables">{{ course_schedules.schedule_start }}</ion-col>
 <ion-col col-2 class="tables">{{ course_schedules.schedule_end }}</ion-col>

 <ion-col col-3 style="display:inline-flex" align="right">
    <button ion-button color="secondary" class="menuButton" (click)="addToCart()">Add to cart</button>
</ion-col>
```

**Question:** I'm able to create the UI, and change and read the values on selection/value change of the drop-down. But how can I get the dropdown's selected value while clicking the 'Add to cart' button? Could you please suggest a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i solved this by using the following code:

In HTML:-

```
<select id="my-input-{{i}}">
        <option *ngFor="let schedule_lessons of course_schedules.schedule_lessons;let j= index" value="{{schedule_lessons.lessons}}-{{schedule_lessons.price}}">{{schedule_lessons.lessons}} Lessons (€ {{schedule_lessons.price}}/Lesson)</option>
    </select>
```

In .ts file:-

```
inputElement: any; 
addToCart(i){
this.inputElement = document.getElementById("my-input-"+i);
alert(this.inputElement.value);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the value of the select to an property of your model.

So add for example the property **selectedValue** to your model and bind the select to it. Then you can access the value in your button with course_schedules.selectedValue:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="course_schedules.selectedValue">
   <option *ngFor="let schedule_lessons of course_schedules.schedule_lessons;let j= index" value="{{schedule_lessons.lessons}}-{{schedule_lessons.price}}">{{schedule_lessons.lessons}} Lessons (€ {{schedule_lessons.price}}/Lesson)</option>
</select>
<button ion-button color="secondary" class="menuButton" (click)="addToCart(course_schedules.selectedValue)">Add to cart</button>
```